# PHPMailer error attaching 22mb file size

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I made a php project which sends email and has an attachment by default.
I'm using this Library https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer . However when I tried to send a pdf file with a 22mb of size I get Internal 500 Server Error on my browser console. I tried using pdf files with less than 1mb of size and other files like jpg and it works fine. Only the 22mb file. What could be the problem? Is it on my php settings? and if yes, which one? Or is it on the library itself? 
Thanks.

Comment: It's probably the memory limit in PHP, or the max upload size. Why are you trying to send a 22MB attachment anyway? You'd be better off storing the file on your server and just sending a link to it so they can download it, or using a service such as wetransfer.

Comment: That's what I want to do just upload it to the cloud and let the recipient download it, but, .. my boss required me to do so. I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: It may also be down to your memory limit - PHPMailer may require several times the attachment size during encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I just compress the file size using this tool http://smallpdf.com/compress-pdf .Hope it can help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes need to change

Set them in `php.ini`, your virtual host config, or in a `.htaccess` file. A typical `.htaccess` file would look like this:

```
php_value post_max_size 30M
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
```

**Note:**

- Those settings are not going to have any effect when set via `ini_set`.
- The reason is that PHP needs those values before your script is even
  executed. When an upload occurs, the target script is executed when
  the upload is complete, so PHP needs to know the maximum sizes.

Reference [php upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)